# My Date Format in DGV Table is Messed up any idea how to fix it?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

So the date in my DGV table showed this format (12/31/2022 12:00:00 AM) I tried to get rid of the time to make it (12/31/2022) when I did that my date format got messed up it became (202,231,12). How do I fix it?

```
cm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT OrderID, FORMAT(Orderdate, '%Y-%m-%d') as OrderDate, CustomerID, Username, ProductID, Qty, Price, TotalAmount FROM ordertb WHERE OrderDate LIKE'%" + txtSearch.Text+"%'", con);
```

Comment: I have no idea what a DGV table is but is orderdate a date dataype or string?

Comment: It's in Date format on mysql database

Comment: Then use date_format function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Leave the date as is, change the format used to display the date on the DGV column. Use a parameter of type date to pass a date to the database engine and let it do its work without trying to pass a format to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never get it right if you try to post a string for searching over a column of type date. Instead you should use parameters to avoid SQL Injection and to avoid parsing problems on the string passed to the database.

First you need to check if the input is indeed a datetime value. (the exact format to pass at the TryParseExact depends on your current inputs)

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtSearch.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH.mm", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
             DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime searchedDate)
      
    ... not a date, display error, return....        

// Prepare the sql command avoiding string concatenations but
// using parameters placeholders.
cm = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID,  
                        Username, ProductID, Qty, Price, TotalAmount  
                        FROM ordertb 
                        WHERE OrderDate = @searchedDate", con);

 // Add the parameter and its value. Note that we will require 
 // a parameter of type date and just the date part of the datetime variable.  
 cm.Parameters.Add("@searchedDate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = searchedDate.Date;
 .... execute the query....
```

And to set the format for a specific DataGridView column use
(for example the third column)

```
dataGrid.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Finally, if your column OrderDate stores also the time, then you should use a sligthly different WHERE condition

```
....
WHERE OrderDate >= @startDate and OrderDate < @endDate", con);

cm.Parameters.Add("@startDate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = searchedDate.Date;
cm.Parameters.Add("@endDate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = searchedDate.Date.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function to perform date formatting.

> **DATE_FORMAT(YourTableFieldName,'%m/%d/%Y')**

In your case: `cm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT OrderID, DATE_FORMAT(Orderdate, '%m/%d/%Y') as OrderDate, CustomerID, Username, ProductID, Qty, Price, TotalAmount FROM ordertb WHERE OrderDate LIKE'%" + txtSearch.Text+"%'", con);`

Get more help from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)